# FFT and spatial frequency basic knowledge

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-domain

Using the following website: [on how the Fourier transform works (Interested in the Basic Principle part).](https://web.archive.org/web/20130513181427id_/http://sharp.bu.edu/%7Eslehar/fourier/fourier.html#basic) I found out that if you have 3 pixels closer in the spatial domain you'll get more spaced fringes in the Fourier domain (frequency domain). How could one explain this ?

Also I don't understand why our 3 closer points would have a lower spacial frequency ? If they're closer then the distance ($\lambda$) separating them is lesser thus the frequency ($\propto \frac{1}{\lambda}$) is greater ?

Comment: "spatial domain" and "frequency domain" are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I don't understand why our 3 closer points would have a lower spacial frequency ?

Wider spaced fringes or points in the Fourier domain means a *higher* frequency, not a lower frequency.  They are spaced further away from 0, which means they are higher in value.   The further away from the center in the frequency domain, the higher the frequency.

> If they're closer then the distance (λ) separating them is lesser thus the frequency (∝1λ) is greater ?

Yes

Comment: Ok I See ! Trank you !